# MongoDB - How to add findandmodify privilege to a user

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

In my application I am using MongoDB as the database and `Express + Mongoose` for handling the codes. I have added a user to the database and given the `readWrite` role for the user, now I can fetch the data from the database. But when I am trying to insert a collection using the `save` function in `Express + Mongoose` I got the following error message and I couldn't find how to add the `findandmodify` privilege to the user.

```
 {"name":"MongoError",
   "ok":0,
   "errmsg":"not authorized on od-database to execute  command { findandmodify: \"identitycounters\", 
   query: {
      field: \"id\",  
      model: \"Products\" },
   new: 1 , 
   remove: 0, 
   upsert: 0,
   update: { $inc: { count: 1 } } }","code":13}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please share the pieces of code that show the database name, how you are calling `mongoose.createConnection` and how you are giving the permission to the user. Thanks!

Comment: Please show us your codes on backend, then we will help you to recover this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I test one user with [`readWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#readWrite) role to connect `mongoDB` do the `save` and `findAndModify` operation on *non-system* document, both of them could be done successfully.

Please make sure

- The correct username and password to connect the db in the `mongoose.createConnction` or `mongoose.connect`.
- This user does exist in the `db.system.users` with `readWrite` role.
- The `readWrite` user only can modify data on all *non-system* collections the [system.js](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-collections/#<database>.system.js) collection

Answer (score 0):

Try giving him the `dbAdmin` role.

Answer (score 0):

Or try to disable authorization or add user that connects to the database.
An example of adding a user to the database:

```
db.createUser({
   user: "admin", 
   pwd: "test", 
   roles: [ { role: "dbAdmin", db: "shop" } ] 
})
```

Where:

- `db:"shop"` - is name database
- `pwd: "test"` - password database
- `user: "admin"` - the user through which the connection to the database, example `db.auth('admin', 'test')`

Answer (score 0):

If `bypassDocumentValidation` is specified for `findAndModify`, the `dbAdmin` role, or a custom role with the `bypassDocumentValidation` permission is needed.

The boolean parameters should preferably be specified as `true` or `false` instead of `0` and `1` as well